# What are the differences between private var b1 = "a1" and private var b2 by mutableStateOf("a1")?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There are two variables `b1` and `b2` in Code A.  It seems that there are all `String` variable, as you can see in Image A.

**Question 1：** What are the differences between `private var b1 = "a1"` and `private var b2 by mutableStateOf("a1")`?

**Code A**

```
class TodoViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var b1 = "a1"
    private var b2 by mutableStateOf("a1")
```

**Image A**
[image]

**BTW**

**Question 2:** Image B is from the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-state#8); it seems that there are some differences between them, but I can't completely understand it.  Could you tell me them?

**Image B**
[image]

**And more**

**Question 3:** In the article, why doesn't the author use  `private var currentEditPosition = mutableStateOf(-1)` instead of  `private var currentEditPosition1 by mutableStateOf(-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b1` is a regular `String` that when the value changed the composables that using the variable will not recomposed or updating automatically.

`b2` is actually a `MutableState<String>` which is when the value changed any composables that using it will be automatically recomposed.

You can not see the difference between it because you're using Kotlin delegate `by` for assigning the `b2` variable. If you use `=` for assigning a variable with `mutableStateOf` you should use `variable.value` to get and set the value.

Comment: Thanks! but Image A display both b1 and b2 as String.

Comment: I told you it because of the Kotlin delegate `by`

Comment: Ttanks!  In the article, why doesn't the author use `private var currentEditPosition = mutableStateOf(-1)` instead of `private var currentEditPosition1 by mutableStateOf(-1)`?

Comment: if they want to use `private var currentEditPosition = mutableStateOf(-1)` then they should use `currentEditPosition.value` to set and get the value as i mentioned in the answer.

The reason to use the delegate is to simplify it

Answer (score 0):

`mutableStateOf` is an `observable` state holder, changes to its value notify its observers. In a sense you can think of it as similar to `LiveData`.

You can use `mutableStateOf` when you want your UI to react to changes to your state, if you have a composable that reads your b2 value, as in this example

```
Text(
    text = b2.value
)
```

then by changing your `mutableStateOf` the text composable will automatically recompose and update its content.